# XCode warning: argument 3 discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, warnings

XCode is giving me a warning that I can't figure out why.

```
@interface SFHFKeychainUtils : NSObject {

}

+ (BOOL) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error;
@end
```

In another class I call storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:, see:

```
- (void)armazenarLogin:(NSString *)login withPassword:(NSString *)password {
    if (login != nil && password != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:login andPassword:password forServiceName:kKeychainServiceName updateExisting:YES error:&error]; // warning here
    }
}
```

This is the warning:

> Passing argument 3 of
>   'storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:'
>   discards qualifiers from pointer
>   target

But I'm passing a pointer to NSError. How do I solve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument 3 is serviceName, isn't it? Check its declaraion. I bet it's const.

Comment: Thank you. You're right kKeychainServiceName was declared as const.